# Inserting a case/when into a select statement

Tags: sql, linq, case

I am trying to change the `@ClientID` (int) into a string when to read in my message body. This what I have so far:

```
BEGIN
  SELECT @message = 'error'
  SELECT @message = @message + 'client:' + @ClientID + char(13)
END
```

How would i enter a case into this select statement to read?

```
CASE
  WHEN @ClientID = 1 THEN 'McDonalds' 
  WHEN @ClientID = 2 THEN 'BK'
  WHEN @ClientID = 3 THEN ....etc
END
```

Comment: Is the text a name column that you can lookup using the `@ClientID`?

Comment: You might need to clarify how this related to linq (the tags you used suggest it should be) - it looks purely sql to me...

Comment: yes i have seperate table for clientID and clientname

Answer (score 1):

Even though you can write a gigantic `CASE` clause, like the one you are doing, I would strongly recomment to use a simple `JOIN` with the `client` table... assuming you have one. Something like:

```
select m.message, c.name
  from message m
  join client c on m.client_id = c.id
  where c.id = @ClientID
```

This is much shorter, less work, less error prone, and easy to read.